# Finding running processes in shell script

Tags: shell, putty

I have shutdown all services on the server using putty.How do I find which all services are still running using the grep command? Also how do I kill these services using process id?

Comment: Which distro, version? Which commands are you using? Maybe `service your_service status`?

Comment: To shutdown tomcat servcies. Figured it out.

Comment: Use ps -aef|grep and kill -9

Comment: Please don't use `kill -9` Let the process finish properly first.

Comment: so if i wanna shutdown and restart the server and make sure all processes are shutdown before restarting it ,how do you suggest I do it?

Comment: @Ziyad That’s usually exactly what a shutdown does. What makes you think you have to do anything manually?

Comment: @Biffen Cause usually even i shutdown there are still some processes running which i have to force shutdown by finding the process id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below commands:

1. To list all the running processes:

   ```
   ps -ef
   ```
2. To list down all processes of a particular user:

   ```
   ps -u userId
   ```
3. To list a particular process:

   ```
   ps -ef | grep processName
   ```
4. To list down a particular process run by a particular user:

   ```
   ps -u userId | grep processName
   ```

Now to kill a process:

While you use `ps` command it list like below:

```
UID    PID  PPID   C    STIME TTY         TIME CMD
user1  398     1   0   Mar 08 ?        1331:39 /usr/sbin/nscd
user2  1388    1   0   Mar 08 ?          11:52 /usr/lib/netsvc/yp/ypbind
```

Now to kill a process you need the process ID that is `PID` here.

Now to kill a process run by user `user1`:

```
kill -9  398  ( sure kill - Not safe)
kill -1  398  ( safe kill - let the process to complete its talk)
kill -15 398  ( safe kill like -1)
kill -8  398  ( Safe kill like -1)
```

Hope this will help you.